# How can I move the links on one inline?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, inline, show-hide

I have tried this CSS, but when you click on the fist link the other two will move at the bottom, same for the other links.
I have tried to change the initial code and put the links in one class, but I don't know that much JavaScript, so probably my modifications are very wrong. 
How can I move the links on one line ? So that when you click on one link the toggled list appears without affecting the link position, so all the links will still be on one line.

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
      $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $div.hide()
        }  else {
           $div.show();
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
        if (!p) {
              $(".dropdown-container").hide();
        }
    });

});

CSS
.dropdown{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Initial code
http://jsfiddle.net/6t6BP/4/
Modified by me code
https://jsfiddle.net/Lavi2/yyfhrss0/

Comment: To change the order of rendering rather than the order of html tags, you have to use `relative` and `absolute` positions.

Comment: Suggest you look for some css menu tutorials

Comment: as i understand you need this .dropdown{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6BP/448/

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make the `dropdown-container` to not push elements down. You can do that, in your case, with `position:absolute` and position it `relative` to the link that triggers it.

P.S. that is not just javascript, it's jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
      $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $div.hide()
        }  else {
           $div.show();
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
        if (!p) {
              $(".dropdown-container").hide();
        }
    });
     
});
```

```css
.dropdown{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative
}
.dropdown-container {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
      $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $div.hide()
        }  else {
           $div.show();
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
        if (!p) {
              $(".dropdown-container").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.dropdown{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.dropdown-container ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```